# Edit wpf Gui objects in a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, backgroundworker

I made a program which imports some `polyline` data for a file. After that I have to perform some shift tasks with the wpf `polyline` elements. Initially I made just one iteration and the blocking of the Gui during calculation was no problem. But if I make many shifting iterations the Gui is blocked for a while. Therefore, I added a `BackgroundWorker` which should solve the problem. The structure of my program can be seen here:

```
class MainGui
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    List<Polyline> _lines;
    int _iterationCount = 10;

    public MainGui()
    {
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
    }

    public void MainTask()
    {
        _lines = Import.ImportLines();

        DrawLines(_lines);
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _iterationCount; i++)
        {
            ShiftTask.DoShift(_lines);

            // worker.ReportProgress((int)((_workerProgressBase - _overlFid[0].Count) / _workerProgressBase * 100));
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)((_iterationCount - i) / _iterationCount * 100));

            // here I would like to update my canvas
        }
    }

    private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void DrawLines(List<Polyline> lines)
    {
        // draw lines on wpf canvas
    }
}
```

I have now two Problems:

1. Because my `polyline` elements belongs already to the MainGui Thread it's throw a `System.InvalidOperationException`. which I tried to solve with the `Dispatcher`. But if I add this code, my Gui is blocked again. What is a good way to pass the referenced object `polyline` to the worker?

   ```
   this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
   {
     ...// your code here.
   });
   ```
2. After each iteration I would like to update the `polylines` on my canvas but unfortunately this isn’t working atm. and also my `ProgressBar` is not updating until the end of the iteration. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I usually pass object to backgroundworker in the constructor.   Did you register the Progress event?  worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);

Comment: Yes, tried also this. I edited the pseudo code to make it clear. Thx

Comment: you shouldn't pass WPF objects anywhere, you should pass the view model object instead

Comment: Ok, this sounds interesting. Do you have any hit for me how to do it the right way?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx thats the best source for explaining the MVVM pattern, the basic idea is that your data changes only happen on the VM then the bindings inform the GUI that it needs to refresh as the binding is notification based cross threading is less of an issue

Comment: bare in mind that the default collections are not thread safe. so either use one from the concurrent namespace or  enclose add and remove operations in invoke's so only the primary threat modifies the collection

Comment: It is not visible in your example, but it is very important: Most of the time in background worker is calculation or painting? If most is painting it makes no sense to do it in background thread, then use System.Windows.Forms.DoEvents() in every iteration it will cause UI responsive. If most of time is caculation then do it in background thread and paint using Dispatcher.Invoke() -> but ONLY part of code wich is really doing painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I made a short excurse to check whether I’m able to solve my problem with the MVVM pattern, I decided that MVVM is too hard for me to implement in my program and it would take me too long. So I searched for another solution which I found and would like to show you.

**Solution:**

I implemented parallel to the `polyline` element a `List<List<Point>>`. I preform all shifting tasks on the Points in the list and when I like to update my Gui in the `BackgroundWorker` I despatch this task (see code in the initial post) to the main thread and override the Points of the `polyline` with `foreach`. Now my Interface is responsive and after every iteration step I can update my Gui. This way I solved both problems.